# Puppeteer multiline waitForFunction method

Tags: javascript, selenium, ecmascript-6, puppeteer

I'm using the Puppeteer `page.waitForFunction()` method:

```
await page.waitForFunction(`
    (window.hero.x - 1 === ${x} || window.hero.x === ${x} || window.hero.x + 1 === ${x} || window.hero.x === ${x}) && (window.hero.y - 1 === ${y} || window.hero.y === ${y} || window.hero.y + 1 === ${y} || window.hero.y === ${y}) || window.hero.x === ${x} && window.hero.y === ${y}
`);
```

It's working but looks terrible. I want to change it to multiline. [In docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args) there is:

> `page.waitForFunction(pageFunction[, options[, ...args]])`
>
> pageFunction `<function|string>` Function to be evaluated in browser context
>
> To pass arguments from node.js to the predicate of `page.waitForFunction` function:
>
> ```
> const selector = '.foo';
> await page.waitForFunction(selector => !!document.querySelector(selector), {}, selector);
> ```

I tried like this:

```
console.log(x,y); // 24 42
await page.waitForFunction((x, y) => {
    console.log(x, y); // undefined, undefined
    if(x && y) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

but `x` and `y` which I'm trying to pass are undefined. What I'm doing  wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in `x` and `y` - currently they're parameters. You can also simplify your function a little:

```
await page.waitForFunction((x, y) => (x && y ? true : undefined), {}, x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in the `x` and `y` arguments to the `waitForFunction`.

```js
console.log(x,y); // 24 42
await page.waitForFunction((x, y) => {
    console.log(x, y); // undefined, undefined
    if(x && y) {
        return true;
    }
}, {}, x, y);
```